# Firebase write data odd behaviour

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I add data to the stream on the app, it will add, but with null fields. Then if I add data again, it will show the past entry, and the process repeats. Put another way - data that is written shows in the succeeding document (once it is created).

```
onPressed: () async {
      //save data to firebase

      await db.collection("Contacts").add(
        {
          'Name': widget.contact.name,
          'PhoneNumber': widget.contact.phoneNumber,
          'Location': widget.contact.location,
          'Birthday': widget.contact.birthday,
          'Notes': widget.contact.notes
        },
      );
      widget.contact.name = oneController.text;
      widget.contact.phoneNumber = int.parse(twoController.text);
      widget.contact.location = threeController.text;
      widget.contact.birthday = int.parse(sixController.text);
      widget.contact.notes = sevenController.text;

      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/second");
    })
```

Comment: Please share some code that you got the problem.

Comment: Okay I've added some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your controller's values before adding DB. That is why you are adding the null value at first time. Try to replace the priority of your codes like this:

```
     widget.contact.name = oneController.text;
     widget.contact.phoneNumber = int.parse(twoController.text);
     widget.contact.location = threeController.text;
     widget.contact.birthday = int.parse(sixController.text);
     widget.contact.notes = sevenController.text;

     await db.collection("Contacts").add(
      {
       'Name': widget.contact.name,
       'PhoneNumber': widget.contact.phoneNumber,
       'Location': widget.contact.location,
       'Birthday': widget.contact.birthday,
       'Notes': widget.contact.notes
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the order.

```
onPressed: () async {
//save data to firebase
widget.contact.name = oneController.text;
widget.contact.phoneNumber = int.parse(twoController.text);
widget.contact.location = threeController.text;
widget.contact.birthday = int.parse(sixController.text);
widget.contact.notes = sevenController.text;

await db.collection("Contacts").add(
    {
        'Name': widget.contact.name,
        'PhoneNumber': widget.contact.phoneNumber,
        'Location': widget.contact.location,
        'Birthday': widget.contact.birthday,
        'Notes': widget.contact.notes
    },
);
 
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/second");
})
```